# Publishing website get error with resharper and subversion

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, resharper, publish, ankhsvn

I'm using Resharper with Visual Studio 2010 also with TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN as VS Client

I've a website (ASP.net) and when i try to publish it publish fails with this error message

i googled it a lot, with no hope.

```
Error   236 The process cannot access the file 'D:\Development\Project\_ReSharper.DotShoppingCart\PersistentCaches\LOCK' because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the _ReSharper.* folder is excluded from the publish process. If you're using ReSharper 8 or 7.1, you can also specify that the ReSharper caches are stored in the user local settings folder, rather than the solution folder - see ReSharper -> Options -> General.